# 'type' object is not subscriptable when installing jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

When I try to install python libraries like pandas and jupyter, I get this error:

```
...PS C:\Users\EliteBook\PycharmProjects> pip install jupyter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\elitebook\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\elitebook\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\elitebook\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\users\elitebook\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\users\elitebook\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.build_env import get_runnable_pip
  File "c:\users\elitebook\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\build_env.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.spinners import open_spinner
  File "c:\users\elitebook\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\spinners.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "c:\users\elitebook\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "c:\users\elitebook\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.tenacity import retry, stop_after_delay, wait_fixed
  File "c:\users\elitebook\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 397, in <module>
    FutureGenericT = futures.Future[t.Any]
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
PS C:\Users\EliteBook\PycharmProjects>
```